# Interpreting linear regression model fit with categorical variables

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear-model

I'm building a linear regression using the following subsetted pisa data set, and trying to predict the read value using the others.

```
year country television math read
<fctr> <fctr> <fctr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
2018    AUS     2   253.056 353.258 
2018    AUS     3+  609.103 521.900 
2018    AUS     3+  398.535 408.911 
2018    AUS     3+  418.239 310.553 
2018    AUS     3+  664.577 687.343 
2018    AUS     3+  541.329 611.386 
2018    AUS     1   617.026 641.578 
2018    AUS     3+  562.511 418.865 
2018    AUS     2   477.485 474.356 
2018    AUS     2   396.637 485.595
...........
```

I built the following simple model

```
lm_mod <- linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm")

read_fit <- lm_mod %>% 
  fit(read~(year + country + television + math), data = dat)
tidy(read_fit)
```

The resulting fit gives out the following

```
   term       estimate    std.error  statistic     p.value
  <chr>       <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
(Intercept) 74.2627484  2.781776137 26.6961627  8.671823e-156
year2006    -1.5082850  1.781576093 -0.8466015  3.972218e-01
year2009    12.3432532  1.794697822 6.8776220   6.165581e-12
year2012    10.3228726  1.790298108 5.7660076   8.170302e-09
year2015    8.2677621   1.798782755 4.5963094   4.312113e-06
year2018    1.4799688   1.765640424 0.8382051   4.019200e-01
countryGRC  0.7202552   0.822066633 0.8761519   3.809522e-01
countryIDN  -18.8697943 0.922761139 -20.4492728 1.614867e-92
countryMYS  -35.8232519 1.108301323 -32.3226646 1.364385e-226
countryNZL  6.2724764   0.840017977 7.4670740   8.348209e-14
......
```

The year and country are categorical variables, and a term is created for each factor level (countryGRC, countryIDN, country MYS, etc.) How is this interpreted?
Does this result in multiple equations for each year/country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program simply dummy coded your categorical variables. Let's say the variable "read" represents pages read that year. According to your model, on average people read 74.2627484 pages, but in countryNZL they read 6.27 more pages than your reference category, whereas on countryIDN they read -18.8697943 less. Same with the year.

Comment: but how do we know the average value? From your answer, how do we know the value 74.2627484? Is it simply the intercept?

Comment: Yes. The intercept represents the mean value of Y when all X = 0